# How to read a particular cell in a excel sheet through pandas?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am working on a requirement where in I need to insert value on the fly in an excel sheet that is empty. So, to accomplish the goal, I am using Pandas.

I have single column(date), where in multiple rows could be empty. I am reading excel file through pandas. However, I found that if a cell is blank, pandas will ignore it, i.e. it will only show the output of a row that has value. Is that normal. If yes, then how could I go about the requirements?

```
df = pd.read_excel('test1234.xlsx')
print(df)
```

### OUTPUT:

```
       Date
0       ami
1       ami
2       ami
3       ami
4       ami
5       wef
6       wef
7       wef
8       wef
9       wef
10      wef
11      wef
12      wef
13      wef
14      wef
15      wef
16      wef
```

I know that the column has 23 rows hat includes empty cells. I understand that the pandas will not show any output after the end of last row. But what about the rows those are blank in between?

Regards,
Amitesh

Comment: why you can't programmatically add blank lines?

Comment: Please elaborate

Comment: What are you trying to do? what is your end goal?

Comment: @user3521180 `df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv('name.csv'), pd.DataFrame([{'Date': ''} for i in range(7)])], ignore_index=True)`

Comment: you need to use `xlwings` or `openpyxl` i think the engine option is available for pandas. Also you may be reading the wrong sheet.

Answer (score 0):

pandas fills the rows with Nan when empty blocks are in between the non empty rows but in the case of empty rows at the end, it is interpreted as end and ignores them. But if you are aware of number of ignored rows at the end u can do this as below.

```
    from numpy import nan as Nan
    import pandas as pd

    >>> df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['A0', 'A1', 'A2', 'A3'],
    ...                     'B': ['B0', 'B1', 'B2', 'B3'],
    ...                     'C': ['C0', 'C1', 'C2', 'C3'],
    ...                     'D': ['D0', 'D1', 'D2', 'D3']},
    ...                     index=[0, 1, 2, 3])

    >>> s2 = pd.Series([Nan,Nan,Nan,Nan], index=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])
    >>> result = df1.append(s2)
    >>> result
         A    B    C    D
    0   A0   B0   C0   D0
    1   A1   B1   C1   D1
    2   A2   B2   C2   D2
    3   A3   B3   C3   D3
    4  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

this operation can be iterated by the number of required empty rows.

Answer (score -1):

The following should work provided that the `index column` in your excel file is present and fully populated.

```
df = pd.read_excel('test1234.xlsx', index_col=0)
print(df)
```

Comment: @gtmor, my main goal is that the program should prompt an user to enter the dat manually if any cell is empty.